# Flipable overlapping other elements

Tags: qt, qml, qt5, qtquick2

In my QML application I'm trying to create a grid of items that can be flipped at the press of a button. The backside of such an item should then fill a major part of the screen until it is flipped back.

Let's say I start off with the following view of my application

[image: Starting view of the application]

When I press the question mark button of the item in the center then the item is flipped and moved slightly. What I would expect to see after this is the following

[image]

The blue box is the backside of my item and it covers most of the screen. Pressing the 'X'-Button on the top right would again flip the item back.

However what I actually see after flipping the first time is the following

[image]

You can see that parts of the items in my grid are covered by my flipped item and parts are not.

The code I'm using is as follows

```qml
import QtQuick 2.9
import QtQuick.Controls 1.4
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.2
import QtQuick.Window 2.2
    
Window {
    id: main

    width: 640
    height: 480
    visible: true
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    function absolutePos(item) {
        var my_x = item.x
        var my_y = item.y

        if (item.parent !== null) {
            var parent_pos = absolutePos(item.parent)
            my_x += parent_pos.x
            my_y += parent_pos.y
        }

        return {x: my_x, y: my_y}
    }

    GridLayout {
        columns: 5; rows: 3

        Repeater {
            model: 15
            delegate: Item {
                width: main.width / 5 - 10
                height: main.height / 3 - 10

                Flipable {
                    id: flipable
                    anchors.fill: parent

                    property bool flipped: false

                    front: Rectangle {
                        anchors.fill: parent
                        border.color: "black"
                        border.width: 2
                    }

                    back: Rectangle {
                        id: backSide
                        width: 580; height: 400

                        property var absolute_pos: absolutePos(this)

                        border.color: "blue"
                        border.width: 2

                        Button {
                            anchors.top: parent.top
                            anchors.right: parent.right

                            text: "X"

                            width: 30; height: 30

                            onClicked: {
                                flipable.flipped = !flipable.flipped
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    transform: [
                        Rotation {
                            id: rotation
                            origin.x: flipable.width / 2
                            origin.y: flipable.height / 2
                            axis.x: 0; axis.y: 1; axis.z: 0
                            angle: 0
                        },
                        Translate {
                            id: translation
                            x: 0; y: 0
                        }
                    ]

                    states: State {
                        name: "back"
                        PropertyChanges {
                            target: rotation
                            angle: 180
                        }
                        PropertyChanges {
                            target: translation
                            x: 490 - backSide.absolute_pos.x
                        }
                        PropertyChanges {
                            target: translation
                            y: 40 - backSide.absolute_pos.y
                        }
                        when: flipable.flipped
                    }

                    transitions: Transition {
                        ParallelAnimation {
                            NumberAnimation {
                                target: rotation
                                property: "angle"; duration: 300
                            }
                            NumberAnimation {
                                target: translation
                                property: "x"; duration: 300
                            }
                            NumberAnimation {
                                target: translation
                                property: "y"; duration: 300
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

                Button {
                    anchors.top: parent.top
                    anchors.right: parent.right
                    text: "?"
                    width: 30; height: 30

                    onClicked: {
                        flipable.flipped = !flipable.flipped
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I was already trying to achieve the effect by manually setting the `parent` of my `Flipable` to `Window.contentItem` so that it will always be above any other items. However this also doesn't fix the problem since the item will still cover the siblings following the current item.

Also I'm still hoping, there is a solution which doesn't require manipulating the z-order of my items in some arcane way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure what you mean by "some arcane way", but changing the `z` property of your delegate is perfectly fine:

```
delegate: Item {
    z: flipable.flipped ? 1 : 0
    // ...
}
```

You will also probably want to hide the "?" button when flipped:

`visible: !flipable.flipped`

Comment: Oh wow, that is so simple! I feared that I needed some complex z-order arithmetic and/or even some functions to be called each time an item is flipped. I really like this solution.